# Recursive tree GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, tree

im new to this site so please excuse my noobish ways haha.

I'm trying to create more buds on the GUI tree that i have been given.

I have been trying so hard to get this right for the past 3 days but every time i change something it destroys the whole drawing!! 
**The code is:**

```
public class RecursiveTreeExample extends JPanel {

    private DrawTurtle t;
    private static final int width = 400;
    private static final int height = 400;

    public RecursiveTreeExample() {
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        t = new DrawTurtle(width, height);
        draw();
    }
    void draw() {
        int s = 100;
        t.back(s);
        embeddedSample(s, 5);
    }

    void embeddedSample(int size, int iter) {
          if (size > 0 && iter > 0) {

            t.forward(size);
            t.right(45);
            embeddedSample(size/2, iter-1);
            t.left(90);
            embeddedSample(size/2, iter-1);
            t.right(45);
                embeddedSample(size/4, iter+3);                    
            t.back(size);
          }
        }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        t.draw(page);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Turtle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel turtle = new RecursiveTreeExample();

        frame.getContentPane().add(turtle);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? "It destroys the whole drawing" tells us very little.

Comment: how DrawTurtle looks like?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/kedba1.jpg